# acts_as_follower gem is not working in rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

acts_as_follower gem working fine in Rails4 but it is not working Rails5.
https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower

When I integrate and try to use follow function in console I got following error:

> user = User.find(1)
>
> user2 = User.find(2)
>
> user.follow(user2)

If you are using sqlite3 database, I got following error:

> no table found error will be display

If you are using pg database, I got following error:

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

This the source code of demo which contain act_as_follow gem with rails5
**https://github.com/jigarbhatt2711/act_as_follow_demo**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing my gem from

```
gem "acts_as_follower"
```

to

```
gem "acts_as_follower", github: "tcocca/acts_as_follower"
```

issue resolved!